# How to search iPhone address book for specific user name based on variable and not a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, addressbook

Apple provides the following sample code in their QuickContacts project for how to search the address book for a particular user.

```
-(void)showPersonViewController
{
 // Fetch the address book 
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

 // Search for the person named "Appleseed" in the address book
 CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, CFSTR("Appleseed"));

 // Display "Appleseed" information if found in the address book 
 if ((people != nil) && (CFArrayGetCount(people) > 0))
 {
  ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, 0);
  ABPersonViewController *picker = [[[ABPersonViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
  picker.personViewDelegate = self;
  picker.displayedPerson = person;
  // Allow users to edit the person’s information
  picker.allowsEditing = YES;

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
 }
 else 
 {
  // Show an alert if "Appleseed" is not in Contacts
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
              message:@"Could not find Appleseed in the Contacts application" 
                delegate:nil 
             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
             otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
  [alert release];
 }
 CFRelease(addressBook);
 CFRelease(people);
}
```

The line that I'm having trouble with is:

```
// Search for the person named "Appleseed" in the address book
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, CFSTR("Appleseed"));
```

This will search the address book for the person named "Appleseed", but I want to search the address book based on a user that is stored in a variable.  For example, I'm trying:

```
Customer *customer = [customerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = customer.name;

CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, CFSTR(customer.name));
```

The "customer.name" isn't resolving to the value that is stored.  I used NSLog to output the value of customer.name and it holds the expected value.

How can I resolve this variable to a string so it will search the address book properly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is customer.name an NSString?

CFSTR only accepts literal C strings.
To pass an NSString, cast it to CFStringRef:

```
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook,
                                        (CFStringRef)customer.name);
```

Comment: customer is an array, should I be able to cast "customer.name" as an array similar to how you've shown it as an NSString?

Comment: According to your code sample, customerArray (not customer) is an array of Customer objects, customer is an object of type Customer, and name is a property in the Customer object.  "name" seems to be of type NSString since you are assigning it to cell.textLabel.text.  In any case, you need to pass a CFStringRef to that address book method.  A CFStringRef points to one string--not an array.

Comment: Thanks, that helps clear things up.  However, when I try and cast customer.name as CFStringRef, I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in the console when it hits that line.  Any ideas?

Comment: Show how the name property is defined in the Customer.h file.

Comment: I assume you're doing this in cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Make sure customer is not nil for any row or that customer.name is not nil for any row.

Answer (score 4):

only if someone has the same problem - be avare that contacts in iOS simulator cannout be found using `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName` until you rename them, they are somehow broken. if you want to test, sync contacts from facebook, or something like that